# Stock exchange Last price doesn't match price steps

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets

I'm looking at the ASX (Australian Stock Exchange), for the stock ARI, currently the last price was 0.158.  However if I were to try to buy it at that price, Etrade Australia would give me an error about the price not matching the price step.  For a share between the price of 10 to 49.5 cents, bids must be in steps of 0.5 cents, [according to this](https://www.asxonline.com/intradoc-cgi/groups/trading_and_market_information/documents/communications/asx015007.pdf).  How have other parties traded at prices outside the permitted steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These orders at in-between steps have been executed through hidden orders. One such hidden order that may produce this outcome is a 'Centre Point order'.

You can read more about these and other hidden order in the ASX document titled [New Order Types](http://www.asx.com.au/documents/resources/asx_trade_new_order_types.pdf).